# How to add any external JavaScript file in my Ember CLI component?

Tags: ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

[image]

I am new to Ember CLI and I don't know how to add my own util file in my app.

I want to add this [summernote.js](http://hbrysiewicz.com/assets/js/summernote.js) file to my project.

How do I add this file to the components using Ember CLI?

Comment: fixed grammer and casing

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `import` keyword in your component file. Example `app/components/my-component`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import MyUtil from '../utils/my-util';

// ... you can use MyUtil here
// ... rest of file
```

Comment: i am getting an error    Uncaught Error: Could not find module `paint/myutils/summernote` imported from `paint/components/wysiwyg-editor`

Comment: Show me your files structure

Comment: i added images on question.

Comment: You have to use export keyword like in other Ember files if you want to import that file to component file.

Comment: i am using import utils from '../myutils/summernote'; in my component. what i do next

Comment: You reformat summernote file to use structure like util, see how the file should look by using ember g util my-util. You need to use export keyword there.